# Let v_1, v_2, w_1, w_2, w_3 \in R^n

Tags: linear-algebra

In this proof I am going to prove that if v_1 \in Span {w_1, w_2} and v_2 \in Span {w_1, w_3}, then v_1 + 2v_2 \in Span {w_1, w_2, w_3}.

What I've done so far:

Let x and y be two different scalars for the two different span of vectors.

Afterwards, we will allow
v_1 = x_1w_1 + x_2w_2 and v_2 = y_1w_1 + y_2w_3

However, in our case, we must show that v_1 + 2v_2 \in Span {w_1, w_2, w_3}.

Let's have i as a variable that is in the Span {v_1, v_2}.
As a result, i will be equivalent to what we have substituted for the v variables so far, or:
i = (x_1w_1 + x_2w_2) + 2(y_1w_1 + y_2w_3)

We can rearrange this equation in terms of w, so it becomes:
i = (x_1 + 2y_1)w_1 + x_2w_2 + 2y_2w_3

And because we know that i \in Span {v_1, v_2}, v_1 + 2v_2 \in Span {w_1, w_2, w_3}.

I am very sure that I am missing a step in here and I don't know where exactly, but at least I'm on the right track?

Comment: I think you already did it, right? You wrote $i = (x_1 + 2y_1)w_1 + x_2w_2 + 2y_2w_3$. That is a linear combination of $w_1, w_2, w_3$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE! It would be really helpful if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for this question -- it'll be easier to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are doing, but you can simply say that, if $w_1=\alpha v_1+\beta v_2$ and if $w_2=\gamma v_1+\delta v_3$, then$$w_1+2w_2=(\alpha+2\gamma)v_1+\beta v_2+2\delta v_2\in\operatorname{span}(\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}).$$